# Как определить tag у найденного элемента bs4 Python

Tags: python, bs4

Как можно определить tag у найденного элемента?
Пробовал так:

```
print(item.get("tag"))
print(item.img)
print(type(item))
```

Два первых возвращала None, третий выкинуло ошибку.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Project/Parsers_site/spr_ru.py", line 179, in <module>
    spr_ru("https://www.spr.ru/otzyvy/sm-klinika-1111439.html")
  File "D:/Project/Parsers_site/spr_ru.py", line 48, in spr_ru
    print(type(content))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Попробуйте `item.name`

Comment: @Andrey спасибо, что-то я не догадался до этого

Comment: @Andrey можете пометить как ответ

Comment: хорошо, сейчас сделаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя тега можно получить c помощью [`.name`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name)

```
item.name
```